# User externallogin redirect to public host after login

Tags: identity-server, content-delivery, login

We have azure appservice for CD witch can be access through private url and public url. Private url is accessible just from internal network, and public url should be used by customer users.
Customer user tries to reach dashboard page on public url, needs login first, so gets login page. But after login user is redirected to dashboard with private url and get 404 error. After putting public url for dashboard they are authorized to user website.
From my understanding after login on public url user should be redirected to public dashboard.
In hostname I have provided two hosts.

I think issue for this is that in externallogincallback in response headers "Location" is set to private url
[image]
We are using SXA 1.9, Sitecore 9.1.1 and also login external provider for Saml login with Azure Active Directory.
What have I missed? 
Any idea what can be wrong?

---

We have found a solution is to this issue.
Description and solution you can find here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/application-gateway/troubleshoot-app-service-redirection-app-service-url